# Nuxt JS website does not load on only iPhone, working fine everywhere else

Tags: iphone, nuxt.js

No problem with Android and other browsers, even safari. But the problem of loading on only iPhone devices. There is no error on the console. Simply called API and showed some data from response

Comment: Can you share some more information? What version of nuxt, your nuxt.config.js and how you’re deploying your site would be helpful.

Comment: I am using nuxtjs version 2.15.7, I just simply run `npm run generate`, it's generating all files inside of dist directory,

Comment: Did you use Safari on Mac? The best approach for this is use a mac book device and check it on its Safari browser with developer tools turned on. Then you can see the errors. It should be an error or not compatible features for WebKit. And you should remember that in iOS all browsers are just wrappers around Safari, even chrome. One other approach is to handle all the warnings. Because, some of them are just warnings in chromium and can cause critical issues on other browsers.

Comment: We need more information in order to help you. Try adding your config, specifying which version of iOS you’re having issues with, what you’ve done to troubleshoot the issue so far etc. I’ve had similar issues myself, and like many users here I’m sure I can help. But more info is required.

Comment: Thank you @Mani Mirjavadi, according to you comments, I checked my whole CSS, and found out the problems with CSS background transparent, which is not supported on Safari browser. The problem was `background: transparent;` and then I changed to to rgba `background: rgba(255, 83, 83, 0.03);`  It's solved.